# Rails nested resource without parent ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, resources

I have Rails project with nested resources like so:

```
resources :blog do
  resources :category do
    resources :post
  end
end
```

On blog or category views, I want to create a post. I understand I will need both blog and category ids in order to make this happen. Is there a way to get to `post#new` without a category ID?

Comment: Not with those routes. Are you sure those are the routes you really want?

Comment: Yes. My users need to create a post off the blog and category screens. Can I create a temporary category ID and visit the `post#new` screen? Maybe saving a new post can create a new category. What do you think?

Comment: I think your routes are not what you want if it is possible to start creating a post without an already existing category. Nested routes are for situations like comments on a post, where you wouldn't create a comment without a pre-existing post. Here, it sounds like a post just `belongs_to :category` and doesn't require a nested route. You can always validate that a real `category_id` is present when a post is created.

Comment: A post does `belongs_to :category`. So you're saying I can nest categories and post on the same level under products. Not having a category in post params seems to be the only caveat. Is this the only way to go? **EDIT: dude, thank you for helping. you rock**

Comment: @ptd please add an answer so it could get marked and close this question.